# Lying under arrest

Tags: liars, situation

I'm in a custody, under arrest, no contact with the outside world.

I do not know if in that jurisdiction authorities are allowed to lie.

Some real-world knowledge suggest lying by authorities is common: https://www.innocenceproject.org/prevalence-police-lying/

Is there a question (or series of questions) that would allow me to establish whether they are allowed to lie to me?

Comment: Without any clear rules about lying (or telling the truth), it is impossible to answer this question as it stands. Does lying need to be consistent, for example?

Comment: I've seen a movie recently and I wanted to learn how to behave... Preferably I will stay away from legal trouble and even if, then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_warning

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: I don't know what is the correct answer, I don't know if there is a correct answer. Maybe there is a phrase: "what would be the correct answer if you were allowed to lie assuming you are not lying now"? MAYBE... Hard to tell.

Answer (score 9):

There is

> no such question or series of questions

provided

> it's possible that in some jurisdiction the police are allowed to lie about their ability to lie

because

> in such a jurisdiction they can answer everything truthfully *except* that they say they aren't allowed to lie when in fact they are -- and, by assumption, you don't know whether that's true or not.